# React - Creating a reusable Components library (You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

when creating a package which will serve as a library of reusable components(A), I'm getting the error below[1] when trying to use any of its components in another project(B).

When developing in the package itself (A), I get no such errors and all works. The issue only occurs when trying to e.g.:

```
import Home from 'ReusableComps';
...
return (
    <Home /> // <- Error here
...
```

I can get by this error by adding something like the below to my (B) webpack[2], but I reckon that this is not a good solution. Am I missing something in the webpack, babelrc etc. in project (A) perhaps?

Thanks

[1]

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

[2]

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  }
```

Comment: Is normal JSX working in the project?

Comment: Yes, I can import js/jsx file which are located directly in the project (made by me). The issue only happens when I try to import a component from my library which is located in the node_modules itself.